# How to persuade visuals_at to look beyond ViewBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, vispy

I'm currently evaluating [`vispy`](http://vispy.org/) for my interactive plotting needs. While it feels a bit beta-ish I'm rather impressed with its speed. Also API design-wise it looks promising.

One feature I'd need to work is picking plot elements with the mouse. There is one example in the distribution (`0.6.4`) that promises to do precisely that: [`examples/demo/scene/picking.py`](https://github.com/vispy/vispy/blob/master/examples/demo/scene/picking.py). Unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

It displays a single window containing a graph with multiple lines. I can interact with the plot as whole, i.e. zoom and shift, but I cannot select individual lines.

If I monkey-debug the relevant piece of code (print statement is mine, full example is [at github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vispy/vispy/master/examples/demo/scene/picking.py)):

```
@fig.connect
def on_mouse_press(event):
    global selected, fig
    if event.handled or event.button != 1:
        return
    if selected is not None:
        selected.set_data(width=1)
    selected = None
    for v in fig.visuals_at(event.pos):
        print(v)
        if isinstance(v, vp.LinePlot):
            selected = v
            break
    if selected is not None:
        selected.set_data(width=3)
        update_cursor(event.pos)
```

I get `<ViewBox at 0x...>` no matter where I click. `fig` is a `vispy.plot.Fig` instance which is [not well documented](http://vispy.org/plot.html?module-vispy.plot).

How can I make this work, i.e. make `visuals_at` see beyond the `ViewBox` and find the actual `LinePlot` instances?

Comment: The default implementation of [viewbox_mouse_event handler](http://vispy.org/scene.html?highlight=visuals_at#vispy.scene.cameras.BaseCamera.viewbox_mouse_event) just adjusts scale factor when scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround to make the view non-interactive before calling visuals_at.
Afterwards the view can be set to interactive again.

This workaround can be found here in a google groups message [workaround](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vispy/sUNKoDL1Gc0/E5AG7lgPFQAJ)

The post is from the year 2015, so the problem seems to have been known for some time.

**Code**

So add to the code

```
plt.view.interactive = False
```

before calling fig.visuals_at and afterwards do

```
plt.view.interactive = True
```

Afterwards the code for on_mouse_press should look like this:

```
def on_mouse_press(event):
    global selected, fig
    if event.handled or event.button != 1:
        return
    if selected is not None:
        selected.set_data(width=1)
    selected = None
    plt.view.interactive = False
    for v in fig.visuals_at(event.pos):
        if isinstance(v, vp.LinePlot):
            selected = v
            break
    plt.view.interactive = True
    if selected is not None:
        selected.set_data(width=3)
        update_cursor(event.pos)
```

**Test**

[image: Test Output]